# Dual-boot does not work

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, linux-mint

I have a PC with Linux Mint installed on it, and I wanted to install Windows 7 alongside it.

What I have done is:

- Created a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu.
- Restarted the computer, this time with Ubuntu (running from my USB drive).
- Created a partition on the main HD using GParted.
- Formatted the partition to NTFS.
- Restarted the computer, this time through the installation CD for Windows 7.
- Installed Windows 7 with normal settings.

That all worked, and I'm writing this from Windows 7. But the thing is, when I boot my system, I don't get to choose what OS to run.

I checked the settings in msconfig, and in the Boot tab it has just Windows 7.

How can I boot Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you shrank the disc correctly with GPT, then the likely cause would be you overwrote your boot loader.  Windows bootloader (Longhorn, I believe) does not detect Linux discs or add them to the boot menu.  That being said, however, if you open the device manager - it should show an unrecognized portion of the disc missing (equal to your Mint size).

I am not sure which version of grub you use (Assuming you use grub), so you would need to get back in and re-configure GRUB.

> [How to Reinstall Grub into MBR](http://www.av8n.com/computer/htm/grub-reinstall.htm)
>   I would summarize this, but it's a bit long.